# How to make a browser HTTP Auth window non-modal?

Tags: browser, window-focus, dialog

Many scam websites use HTTP Basic Auth windows or JS alert windows to prevent the user from navigating away from the page.

Here's an example of a fake Windows technical support webpage:
[image]

Since the window is modal, it grabs focus and the only way to get away is to kill the browser process.

My question: until this [is implemented in the browser's code](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1431861), is there a way (browser add-on, plugin, etc.) to make these annoying dialogs non-modal?

Comment: Couldn't you just press Abort?

Comment: @slhck usually these kinds of websites will bring up the login directly after you press cancel, the x etc, and only with a valid login, will they vanish. That said, it is up to the browser how they implement this. I use Vivaldi, and they don't have this problem. I can close a tab or switch tabs regardless of these popups because Vivaldi uses non-modal dialogs.

Comment: No way. The only extension which did the job was removed by its owner and probably wouldn't anyway have worked today. You need to wait for this option to be released.